# Is it allowed to pass "this" of derived class to constructor of base class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, undefined-behavior, virtual-functions

Here is the code I originally wanted to write:

```
class A {
public:
    A(someType someData) {
        this->init(someData);
    }
   
    virtual void init(someType) = 0;
}
```

This is not allowed, because at the point when base class constructor is called, instance of the derived class doesn't exist yet. So I changed it to this:

```
class A {
public:
    A(someType someData, A* derived) {
        derived->init(someData);
    }
   
    virtual void init(someType) = 0;
}

class B : public A {
public:
    B(someType someData)
    : A(someData, this) {}
    
}
```

The code compiles and runs without crashing but is it allowed or UB?

Comment: You can pass `this` to the base class, but you cannot use it to access the derived class (that still doesn't exist yet). You *can* save the pointer and use it later, when the construction is complete.

Comment: What code "compiles and runs"? There's no `main`, no objects created, and no way to create either an `A` or a `B` object because there's no override of the pure virtual `A::init`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's just as undefined as calling the virtual function. The instance of `B` isn't constructed until after `A`s constructor completes so you can't call virtual functions on it.

One approach to fix this is to do a two stage construction, fully construct the class, and only then, call the virtual method:

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void init(someType) = 0;

    template <typename T>
    static T construct(someType someData)
    {
       T obj;
       obj.init(someData);
       return obj;
    }
}

class B : public A {
public:
    void init(someType) override
    {}
}

int main()
{
  B b = A::construct<B>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class A {
public:
    explicit A(someType someData, A* derived) {
        derived->init(someData);
    }
    virtual void init(someType) = 0;
};

class B : public A {
public:
    explicit B(someType someData)
        : A(someData, this) {}
    void init(someType) override;
};
```

My understanding is that `B`'s constructor can certainly load `this` and pass it to `A`'s constructor... but, before the function body of `B`'s constructor has been entered, that `this` pointer will still point to only an `A` object. (In fact, before `A`'s constructor's function body has been entered, it won't even point to an `A` yet!)

So when you call `derived->init()` on `A* derived`, `derived` points to an `A`-that-is-not-yet-a-`B`. In particular, it still has `A`'s vptr, pointing to `A`'s vtable, where `A::init` is pure virtual. It has no idea that it ought to be calling `B::init` instead. So you have a call to a pure virtual function, which is UB — and in practice will just abort the program.

In fact you could have tried this out and seen for yourself, without even asking StackOverflow. :) [Godbolt.](https://godbolt.org/z/7T6bE6c8f)